problema al capturar evento submit con editor tinymce
tengo un formulario con un editor tinymce, la cuestion es que al enviar enviar el formulario no puedo capturar el evento submit pues me dice que 'El control de formulario no válido con name=‘contenido’ no puede tener el foco' la cuestion es que es algo que pienso suceda por editor tinymce pues mientras no estaba en el textarea se enviaban bien los datos.


form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit',function(event) {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        newform = [];
        if (!!event.currentTarget.id) {
            newform['action'] = $_GET.a || 'edit';
            newform['id'] = $_GET.e;
            newform['table'] = $_GET.p;
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.currentTarget.length > 1) {
                for(element of event.currentTarget) {
                    if (element.id == 'floatingInput' && !!element.value) {
                        newform[element.name] = element.value;
                    }else if(element.classList.contains('editor') && !!element.value){
                        newform[element.name] = element.value;
                    }
                };
            }
        } else {
            newform['table'] = $_GET.p;
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.currentTarget.length > 1) {
                for(element of event.currentTarget) {
                    if (element.id == 'floatingInput' && !!element.value) {
                        newform[element.name] = element.value;
                    }
                };
            }
        }  
        enviarDatos(newform);
    });




El código que publicas no muestra el comportamiento que describes. ¿Has preparado un [mcve]? Probablemente has olvidado incluir parte del código, el HTML, por ejemplo.

gracias ya lo resolvi

Resuelto. El problema era que el campo textarea donde esta el editor de texto tenia el atributo required  el cual no deja enviar el formulario si no tiene contenido y tinymce no cambia ese textarea ni inserta contenido en el sino que lo oculta, solucion no a;adir atributo required a campos de tipo editor de tinymce
